# <div> tags move up when other is selected

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/aritro33/y6wBy/

And when you hit the compose button on this jsfiddle, a post drops down revealing an assortment of colors above it. Notice how when you click on a color in the middle, or any color for the matter, all the colors to the left of that color move up slightly giving a weird effect. How would it be possible to prevent all the colors on the left of the div selected from moving up and in fact keeping them where they are.

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div id="red" class = "color"></div>
<div id="orange" class = "color"></div>
<div id="yellow" class = "color"></div>
<div id="green" class = "color"></div>
<div id="turquoise" class = "color"></div>
<div id="blue" class = "color"></div>
<div id="purple" class = "color"></div>
<div id="gray" class = "color"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#red {

     background-color: #2ac0a3;
     border-top-left-radius: 5px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
     position: relative;
     bottom: 220px;
     left: 365px;
 }
 #orange {
     background-color: #25ac92;
     position:relative;
     bottom:236px;
     left: 405px;
 }
 #yellow {
     position: relative;
     bottom: 252px;
     left: 445px;
     background-color:#219982;
 }
 #green {
     position: relative;
     left: 485px;
     bottom: 268px;
     background-color: #1d8672;
 }
 #turquoise {
     position: relative;
     left: 525px;
     bottom: 284px;
     background-color: #197361;
 }
 #blue {
     position: relative;
     left: 565px;
     bottom: 300px;
     background-color: #156051;
 }
 #purple {
     position: relative;
     left: 605px;
     bottom: 316px;
     background-color: #104c41;
 }
 #gray {
     height: 16px;
     width: 40px;
     position: relative;
     left: 645px;
     bottom: 332px;
     background-color: #0c3930;
     border-top-right-radius: 5px;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
 }

.active{
     height: 18px;
    width: 45px;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.color').click(function(){ $('.active').removeClass('active'); $(this).addClass('active'); });
```

Comment: You could save a **lot** of code by collapsing all those "click" handlers down into a single function.

Comment: As said above, you could change the entire JS above to something like `$('.color').click(function(){
 $('.active').removeClass('active');
 $(this).addClass('active');
});`

Comment: Each of those "color" `<div>` elements has a different "bottom" value. Why?  Seems like you should (a) not change the size for the "active" element; (b) give each the same position; and (c) give ".color" elements a "1px solid transparent" border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#active` property changes the size of the colors:

```
.active{
    height: 18px;
    width: 45px;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

If you change it to this:

```
.active{
    height: 14px;
    width: 45px;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

the effect seems to go away.

Comment: It's also necessary to take the "height" out of the "#gray" element's CSS.

Comment: not quite, but thank you. You can accept if you like the answer though, I will take that ;-)

Comment: Yeah, sorry it just said I had to wait four minutes before I accepted your answer. @Phlume

Comment: And one last thing, I was trying to get it to look a bit like this when you click on a color: http://dribbble.com/colors/666600 so I need the color to grow a bit in size and be centered, how would that be possible? @Phlume

Comment: you can work with the position of the element and offset the size with a shift in position so that it remains centered...or you can adjust the scale and position with css3.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the CSS for `#gray` has a few other properties, if you mimic the others, the slight movement seems to go away:

```
 #gray {
 position: relative;
 left: 645px;
 bottom: 332px;
 background-color: #0c3930;}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Try attaching a jsfiddle -- I don't quite seem to get what your saying. @Craighead

Comment: the jsfiddle doesn't seem to change when making this change

Comment: Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y6wBy/3/) - perhaps I misunderstood the question.

Comment: yep, it still has the same issue.

Comment: Ahh, I see it now - I was looking at how the lower "Write Header Here" was moving up slightly.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

For me, you may rewrite your CSS at all. To place every Element with position will let you run in to more problems at the end i think.